# I don't understand the reputation limit

Tags: support, reputation

I love SuperUser.com and I am on it all the time, I do not do it for the reputation but it is a very nice bonus for helping people, that being said - it confuses the heck out of me!

I understand that in the FAQ it says you can have a maximum of 200 a day (excluding the answer + bounties) however even when I account for time differences, I do not understand what is happening.

It seems that I have only got 150 reputation and it has locked me out for the day.

[image]

I love the site and would happily give help if reputation wasn't there, but as it is there, I want to understand it! I have seen other seemingly random behaviour like this recently and I just want to know if I have overlooked or done something wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of so many questions.

Comment: I typed reputation in search but found nothing exactly like this, only people talking about the limit, not why / asking support like this. Sorry if duplicate, but please show me a question so I can see it.

Comment: 12008, 8272, 504 and others.

Comment: @Wil - see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8272/the-rep-cap-is-200-per-day-correct

Comment: It's so you don't surpass me, just because I was on a vacation!

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand the down votes, what I wrote to Jon Skeet below counts, I did click today, and whilst it says 215, the includes a bounty, I am below the 200 daily limit! That is why I asked this as support!

Comment: @Wil: bounties count toward the cap. *Everything* counts toward the cap. Bounties and "accept" bonuses will still be applied to your reputation after you've hit the cap, but 'till then they're just normal reputation as far as that cap is concerned. See the link i posted in comments to Jon's answer.

Comment: @lvo, lol, I doubt I will. I just press refresh between projects or calls. I doubt I can keep it up soon as I have a lot of work coming.

Answer (score 6):

According to my [Reputation Tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=&sf=&su=4386&meta=&mode=today&showflair=true), you've gained 215 today.

When you hit the envelope, you need to explicitly click on "Today" to get the real UTC day (which is what the rep limit is based on) instead of the day starting at the server's local midnight. Or you could use my reputation tracker ;)

Comment: Outsourcing the reputation tracking. :D Smart

Comment: Thanks, I like your tracker, but that is what I do not understand - the 75 for Mcafee was a bounty and not from up votes, so it should be excluded from the daily limit!

Comment: @Wil - see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15540/award-bounties-at-the-end-of-the-day

Comment: Thank you - but from the FAQ - "Of course, bounty awards, like all accepted answers, are immune to the daily reputation cap", that is why I asked here - so is it a bug?

Comment: @Wil: they're immune to the cap, but the cap is not immune to them.

Comment: @Shog9, what you said makes sense and was what I was looking for... I did not get that impression from the FAQ. Can you write that in an answer and I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 2):

[This has been hashed out pretty well in previous questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8272/the-rep-cap-is-200-per-day-correct), but since you took the time to [draw on a screenshot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775) I'll copy my comments addressing the apparent discrepancy:

Bounties count toward the cap. **Everything counts toward the cap.** Bounties and "accept" bonuses will still be applied to your reputation after you've hit the cap, but 'till then they're just normal reputation as far as that cap is concerned.

The bonuses awarded to users for an accepted answer (normally 15, additional when there's a bounty on the question) *are* immune to the daily reputation cap... however, the cap is not immune to them: you'll just hit the cap that much faster if your answers get accepted.

Some of the folks who *routinely* hit the rep cap [would dearly love to see this changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15540/award-bounties-at-the-end-of-the-day).

Comment: Thanks - And sorry if I annoyed anyone here, I really thought that this had not been asked before - I read the FAQ and I genuinely did not understand, I typed reputation in search and did not find this. Anyway, I am glad I understand now. Thanks again!